# CONCAT does not recognized null value troubleshooting

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    model,
    max(case when ranking = 1 then concat(expense,' ', expense_percent, '%') end ) top1_expense,
    max(case when ranking = 2 then concat(expense,' ', expense_percent, '%') end ) top2_expense
from
(
    select 
        a.model,
        Expense,
        count(1) Expense_count,
        total,
        round(count(1)/cast(total as float)*100,2) as expense_percent,
        row_number() OVER(partition by a.model ORDER BY count(1) DESC) as Ranking
    from [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION] a
    join
            (
                SELECT 
                        Model,
                        COUNT(1) total
                FROM [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION] 
                where Expense is not null
                group by Model
            )b
    on a.Model = b.Model
    group by a.model, Expense, total
)fin

group by model
order by 1
```

The result is somewhat funny. So basically the query can return NULL value on top2_expense but give nothing on top1_expense

Example of result :

| Top_1_Expense | Top_2_Expense |
| --- | --- |
| A 75% | A 15% |
| 125% | NULL |

*The query that I used should return the part that show 125% as NULL
any suggestions?*

Comment: Side note: looks like the self join could be removed by using a windowed count: `COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Model)`

Answer (score 1):

`concat()` ignores `NULL` values.  So, if any argument is `NULL` it treats it as an empty string.

If you use `+` instead, you will get a `NULL` value if *any* argument is `NULL`.  So I think you want:

```
expense + ' ' + convert(varchar(255), expense_percent) + '%'
```

in the `case` expressions in the outer query.

Comment: any alternative beside this. Since if I do this I got error converting data type varchar to float. Maybe a query to make null values as '-'

Comment: @Ascalon_Dx . . . Use explicit conversion.